# Passing parameter to Angularjs directive template ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/VNDqs8rD7ILG5rB4xSWe?p=preview)

Is it possible to pass a parameter to the directive template in the ng-if?

index.html:

```
<my-directive showName="John"></my-directive>
```

template.html:

```
<h1 ng-repeat="customer in customers" ng-if="customer.name === showName ">
  {{customer.name}} is {{customer.age}}
</h1>
```

Ideally, the above example would only show John's data.
Maybe it is not the right way to do it?
because when I use `scope: { showName = '@' }` in the directive, the `ng-repeat` does not seem to work anymore?

Comment: you have an error there. because you use ng-if on the same level as ng-repeat, your whole expression won't execute if the expression is false (which is initial the case). therefore, you should make a nested div or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a filter instead.

For this to work, you have to change the expression in your template:

```
<h1 ng-repeat="customer in customers | filter:{name: showName}">
  {{customer.name}} is {{customer.age}}
</h1>
```

This will filter just the matching name attributes.

To have a isolated scope, you should bind your attributes to the local scope variables in your directive:

```
scope: {
  customers: '=', //two way binding of the object
  showName: '@'   //string evaluation
}
```

But since you have an isolated scope, you should also add the attribute customers like this:

```
<my-directive show-name="John" customers="customers"></my-directive>
```

and here is the working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zCRiVX35szEKm8fOf693?p=preview)

If you want, you can also go a step further and bind your show-name to an input field:

```
<input ng-model="search" />
<my-directive customers="customers" show-name="search"></my-directive>
```

therefore you have to change the binding also to two way binding:

```
scope: {
   customers: '=',
   showName: '='
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you use

```
scope: {
   showName:'='
}
```

Two things happen:

1. A parameter for the directive is defined with the name `show-name`. Not `showName`.
2. The directive scope gets isolated. That means it loses access to `customers` defined in the parent scope. You will have to pass them too in a parameter.

Also, instead of using `ng-if` and `ng-repeat` you should use a filter on `ng-repeat`. Otherwise you will have priority problems (`ng-if` executed before `ng-repeat`).